# Failed to reload nginx.service: Interactive authentication required

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, command-line

I am working on project using symfony 3,
the project run on nginx server
and i am trying to reload the configuration files with the following command:
"systemctl reload nginx" from the controller.

```
/**
* @Route("/testReloadConfig")
*/
public function testReloadConfigAction(Request $request){

    $output = [];
    $result = null;

    $cmd = 'systemctl reload nginx 2>&1';

    exec($cmd, $output, $result);

    return new JsonResponse([
        'result' => $result,
        'output' => $output,
    ]);
}
```

The response: 
    {"result":1,"output":["Failed to reload nginx.service: Interactive authentication required.","See system logs and \u0027systemctl status nginx.service\u0027 for details."]}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most probably `nginx` doesn't run with user `root` which is what you need to use `systemctl`. Therefore you should execute your command using `sudo`.

Now there are different ways of running a command from web-server with `root` privileges:

- Run `nginx` with user `root` which is **highly discouraged** for obvious security reasons
- Add only this specific command to `sudoers` as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password) in order to run it with `root` privileges without any password prompt
- Pass your `root` password through `echo` as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095751/run-php-shell-exec-like-root-user)
- Write a bash script with limited functions as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598231/how-to-run-php-exec-as-root)

But of course you might find something else searching on for it.