# Restart Services on GCE Instance Using Cloud Build

Tags: bash, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

I have a GCE instance that I push code to using Cloud Build. I need to restart services on that VM once the code has been pushed. Here's what my Cloud Build YAML looks like:

```
steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
  - '-c'
  -  |
      for d in *; do
              gcloud compute scp $d user@instance-1:/path/to/directory --zone=asia-south1-a --recurse

      done

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  -  |
      gcloud compute ssh user@instance-1 --zone=asia-south1-a --command="service uwsgi restart"

timeout: 1200s
```

While the first step works fine, while trying to restart the service, I receive the following error:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=Hello cookie=1 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.3477 object=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=1 reply_cookie=1 error=n/a
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=AddMatch cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=AddMatch cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Calling manager for ReloadUnit on uwsgi.service, replace
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=ReloadUnit cookie=4 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Failed to reload uwsgi.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status uwsgi.service' for details.
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=RemoveMatch cookie=5 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus object=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=RemoveMatch cookie=6 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.systemd1 object=/org/freedesktop/systemd1 interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager member=ReloadUnit cookie=4 reply_cookie=0 error=n/a
Failed to reload uwsgi.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status uwsgi.service' for details.
```

I've tried disabling the interactive authentication mechanism as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/864717/unable-to-restart-a-systemctl-service-remotely-as-a-non-root-user) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/how-to-disable-requiretty-for-a-single-command-in-sudoers) but that hasn't worked. Please help.

Comment: Try running it with the sudo as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500748/failed-to-reload-nginx-service-interactive-authentication-required

Comment: Can a [reset](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/reset) solve your issue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I don't think so. A reset would also lead to fairly larger downtime that's not affordable.

Comment: Agree, the VM reboot and the downtime is longer. According with your constraint, it could be a solution. But not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating this issue, I suggest a workaround, which is to make a listener run by root, that checks if a file exists. This file is created by the user from Cloud Build when there is a build (with `touch`, for example). If the file exists, the listener deletes it and restarts the service. The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Listener to be run by root. When user from
# Cloud Build touches $FILE, root removes it
# and restarts the service from within the VM.

FILE="/home/user/file"

function listen()
{
        if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
            rm $FILE
            service uwsgi restart
            sleep 60
        else
            sleep 10
        fi
}

while true
do
    listen
done
```